# map.on('click') limit number of pins added to map - leaflet js

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet js and I want a user to be able to add a single point to the map (and not get trigger happy and add lots of pins), what do I need to do to modify the below so that this can happen.

```
map.on('click', function(e){
   var Marker = L.marker(e.latlng,{
       draggable: true
   }).addTo(map);
```

Si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an jQuery-based example where the user can click a button to enable adding a single marker. After adding a marker, the map click function is removed from the map - no additional markers can be added until the button is pressed again.

**HTML**

```
<button>Click to add a single marker</button>
```

**JavsScript/jQuery**

```
$(button).on('click', function() {
    enableAddMarker();
}

function enableAddMarker() {
    map.on('click', addMarker)
}

function addMarker(e) {
    var Marker = L.marker(e.latlng,{
         draggable: true
    })
    Marker.addTo(map);
    map.off('click', addMarker);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:
Add a global variable to your code `var count = 0;`.
In your function add two things a line, `count += 1`.
In the function have an, 
`if (count < 10){ draggable: true } else {draggable: false}`.